# Why value from values-w820dp/dimens.xml file is not applied in Nexus 7 and 10 emulators?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In my Android app I have a text view with start and end paddings.

```
<TextView
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/my_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/my_padding">
</TextView>
```

The paddings are set in **values/dimens.xml** file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_padding">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

There is a larger padding specified for wide layouts in **values-w820dp/dimens.xml** file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_padding">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

My problem is that when I try to test the app in Nexus 7 or Nexus 10 emulators **in landscape** it still uses the small padding. Why does it ignore the value form the values-w820dp/dimens.xml file?

Android Studio version 1.5, emulator version: 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one possible reason that it load the layout when it's portrait and never reload or update when rotate to landscape.